# Sending a message to telegram (text from input) with Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular-material, telegram, angular9, angular10

Have anyone an idea how can i send an text message from an mat-input input in my angular project to an telegram group chat? I have already a link that sends a message when clicked. But i want my input value to be sent.

Comment: What have tried? What issues did you run into?

Comment: sendMessage() {
    console.log('It works')
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogContentSupport);
    const msg = this.message.msg + '\n' + this.message.userName;
    this.contactusService.sendMsgtoGroup(encodeURIComponent(msg));
  }

}

Comment: sendMsgtoGroup(msg: string): Observable<ApiResponse> {
    return this.http.get<ApiResponse>(`${this.telegramAPIUrl}${msg}`);
  }
}

Comment: No issues, function is ready. Just have no idea how to connect the Telegram API link to my input

Comment: http://api.telegram.org/ (BOT TOKEN)/sendMessage?chat_id=-(PASTE ID HERE)&text=

Comment: ok. Please add this code to the question I'm sure an answer will come up